# Character counter for form inputs- not counting

Tags: javascript, php, html, character, counter

Anyone have any insights into why this code isn't displaying the characters left and only displaying the maximum amount of characters, I have gone through it several times I can't seem to find the error.

HTML

```
<form class="comment" method="post" action="postComment.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="Cname" onKeyUp="charLeft(this.value,30,'n')"><br/><span id="nCharLeft"></span><br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Cemail" onKeyUp="charLeft(this.value,50,'e')"><br/><span id="eCharLeft"></span><br/>
    <textarea rows="4" placeholder="Please leave a comment." name="Ccomment" onKeyUp="charLeft(this.value,300,'c')"></textarea><br/><span id="cCharLeft"></span><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Post Comment"><br/>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function charLeft(val,len,indi) {
    var output = indi + "CharLeft";
    if (val.length==0) { 
        return;
    }
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
       document.getElementById(output).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","charLeft.php?q="+val+"&m="+len,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PHP (charLeft.php)

```
<?php
$v = $_REQUEST['v'];
$m = $_REQUEST['m'];
$len = strlen($v);
$charleft = $m - $len;

echo $charleft==="1" ? "$charleft character left." : "$charleft characters left.";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you AJAX call, you are sending value in q but accessing it as 
$v = $_REQUEST['v'];

So, either change in the AJAX call as 
xmlhttp.open("GET","charLeft.php?v="+val+"&m="+len,true);

or change in PHP as 
$v = $_REQUEST['q'];

Answer (score 0):

You sent "charLeft.php?q="+val+"&m="+len, but get the value by $v = $_REQUEST['v'];

Try with

```
$v = $_REQUEST['q'];
```